# What is the Profit for a scenario on the day before expiration?

Tags: options, call-options

I have 1 contract of a CALL OPTION of a **XYZ** stock. The strike price is **$155**. The purchase price is **$15**. The Expiration is **Jan 3 2020**. The current price of the stock is **$161**. I paid **$1515** for owning them.

The scenario is that on **Jan 2**, the price is **156**. If I **sell the CALL Option** on **Jan 2**, is my profit calculation as shown below:

Profit: $156 - $155 = $1 - $15 = ($14)

Is the profit is **negative 14**, so for an investment of **$1515**, I lost **$1400** and I have only **$115** if I sell the CALL OPTION?

Comment: Your last paragraph makes no sense at all.  I would suggest that you consider reading an options book so that you can obtain a sound basic understanding of option calculations.

Comment: What book do you suggest? Currently I'm watching all the videos and blogs.

Comment: Read  "Options as a Strategic Investment" by Lawrence G McMillan. Well written with many clear examples. Will give you a fundamental understanding of basic option strategies (covered calls, short puts, spreads, etc.). It also explains a variety of other option strategies and should they intrigue you, you can read more. Pick up an old edition for peanuts. If you find that you are interested in more complex strategies, pick up the newest edition. "Option Volatility & Pricing: Advanced Trading Strategies and Techniques" by Sheldon Natenberg is good for understanding the technical aspects (Greeks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loss is $14.00. 100 shares per contract = $1,400 loss